# Factoring the Ring of Integers into Ideals

Tags: ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $K$ be a number field. Let $\frak p$ be a prime ideal in $\mathcal O_K$. Let $u\in \mathcal O_K$ and $m\in \mathbb N$. I've been told that $|u|_{\frak p} = |m|_{\frak p} = 1$ where $|\cdot|_{\frak p}$ denotes the $\frak p$-adic norm. Why should this be true?

Given the definition of $|\cdot|_{\frak p}$, this is equivalent to saying that when we factor $u\mathcal{O_K}$ and $m\mathcal{O_K}$ into prime ideals, $\frak p$ has multiplicity 0, but I still don't see why this should be true.

Comment: This question could have a *very* long answer. If you're expecting anyone to help you with this, you need to provide more context. For example, what do you know about such extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$? What theorems have you proved about the structure of $\mathcal{O}_K$? What do you know about ring theory in general?

Comment: It is not "factoring the ring of integers" so much as "factoring" ideals that forms a large topic.  Essentially in $\mathbb{Z}$ the ideals are principal, but the extended rings of integers you bring up are not necessarily principal ideal domains, nor even (as it turns out) unique factorization domains.  This is the motivation for looking at "factoring" ideals rather than elements of these rings.

Comment: Ok, I've made the question more concrete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without additional conditions on (say) $u$ and $m$, this is certainly false. For example, if $\mathfrak{p}$ is prime in $\mathcal{O}_K$, let $u$ be any nonzero element of $\mathfrak{p}$. Then $(u)\subseteq \mathfrak{p}$, so that $|u|_{\mathfrak{p}}>0$. For $m$, if $\mathfrak{p}$ lies over the rational prime $p$, let $m=p$. Then $|m|_{\mathfrak{p}}>0$.